# About Git clone and branch

Tags: git

My understanding is that Git clone bring everything from remote locally. 
Now, when I want to work on a branch that is part of repository, why do I have to create a local branch because the branch already exists and as I have cloned it, it should exist in the local clone also

Comment: You should be able to simply `git checkout` a remote-tracking branch name, and it will automatically set up the local branch.

Comment: You clone, but at a time you can checkout one branch. You can checkout remote branches.
Thanks

Comment: > git checkout origin <branch>

Comment: No, just `git checkout branch`, where `branch` is the name of the remote branch.

Answer (score 2):

well.. you are right, git clone (...) get in you local machine the repo.

git branch (..) create a local branch.

Now if the branch you want to use is already in the repo that you just cloned, you dont need to re create the branch (you can, but its not necesary). you can just use git checkout  without a previous git branch (..)

Example: repo got 2 branches. master and dev
*git clone (url bla bla)

*cd /repoName
(now you are in master branch)

*git branch -a (this will show you all branches, red are remotes, white local, and green actual branch)

*git checkout dev

And thats all, you go to dev branch, and you didnt created it. (only for already existing remote branch)

Comment: git checkout dev is not working. it says enter code here`
enter code here`You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: LOL, surelly "dev" branch not exist , it was just an example. you have to checkout to and existing remote branch.

Comment: give me the github url repo if you want more specific help

Comment: I know ... in my local repo, I did not put "dev" ... the branch name is develop in my local repository and that is what I tried ... I was just explaining the issue using your example ...

Comment: oh, sry! well if that happend verify this. 1) git branch -a and look for remotes and local branch existences. 2) if the branch color is red you must be able to checkout there. (if its white you already got it locally)

Comment: only master shows in white. Rest are in red. Some the members above seem to suggest that if I do "git checkout develop" it should work, which isn't the case ... it comes up with detached head issue for me ...

Comment: mmm... if you see develop branch in red and git checkout develop it must work. 1) did you try cloning again? 2) try with a different repo?

Comment: It is detached because the branch is remote and so it is read-only. If you want to checkout to the branch and work on it you have to create a local branch. Use `git checkout -b local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name`

Comment: thanks, Jona and Luis. I think git checkout -b develop origin/develop works. The mind block I am having is why should I be creating a local branch (-b) when I expected it to be available to me when I did clone. Apparently, this is not how Git works. For every branch in origin, explicitly we have to checkout and create a local branch to track it. When clone is done, there are no branches that reflect branches on origin (probably, except for master)